# PHPUnit x Symfony : coverage 0% outside of src directory

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit, code-coverage

After multiple searches, I still can't find the reason why the coverage generation (via PhpStorm coverage or via `--coverage-html` directly) does not generate coverage for the tests outside the `src` folder despite the tests being well carried out.

I tried with Xdebug coverage and with pcov.

To explain, my project has its main code in the `src` folder and additional modules in the `modules` folder. Each module has its own composer.json which is merged with the core's composer.json and each module has its own namespace.

Structure :

```
Project
 | composer.json
 | src/ (namespace App\)
 | tests/ (namespace App\Tests\)
 | modules/
 --| Airport/
   --| src/ (namespace Module\Airport\src\)
   --| tests/ (namespace Module\Airport\tests\)
   --| composer.json
 --| OtherModule/
   --| src/ (namespace Module\OtherModule\src\)
   --| tests/ (namespace Module\AirOtherModuleport\tests\)
   --| composer.json
```

phpunit.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1"/>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true"/>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true"/>
        <server name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1"/>
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_REMOVE" value=""/>
        <server name="SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION" value="9.5"/>
        <server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel"/>
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>tests</directory> <!-- Core tests -->
            <directory>modules/*/tests</directory> <!-- Multiple modules tests -->
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <coverage>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory> <!-- Core coverage -->
            <directory suffix=".php">modules/*/src</directory> <!-- Multiple modules coverage -->
        </include>
    </coverage>

    <!--<listeners>
        <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener"/>
    </listeners>-->

    <extensions>
        <extension class="\DAMA\DoctrineTestBundle\PHPUnit\PHPUnitExtension"/>
    </extensions>
</phpunit>
```

PHPUnit version :

```
PHPUnit 9.5.20 #StandWithUkraine

Runtime:       PHP 7.4.28
Configuration: /var/www/html/phpunit.xml.dist
```

PHP & Xdebug version :

```
/var/www/html $ php -v
PHP 7.4.28 (cli) (built: Mar 11 2022 08:54:27) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.28, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2022, by Derick Rethans
```

Xdebug config :

```
/var/www/html $ php -i|grep xdebug
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini,
xdebug
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support
             Enabled Features (through 'xdebug.mode' setting)             
xdebug.auto_trace => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => 172.17.0.1 => 172.17.0.1
xdebug.client_port => 9003 => 9003
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_params => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.coverage_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.default_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.log => no value => no value
xdebug.log_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.mode => develop,debug => develop,debug
xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.overload_var_dump => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_connect_back => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log_level => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_timeout => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => (setting removed in Xdebug 3) => (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.start_with_request => yes => yes
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3) => (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.use_compression => 0 => 0
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

`bootstrap.php` supports vendor autoload. The `autoload_static.php` file contains the file in question and its namespace, obviously because tests are working.

When PhpStorm start the test for example :

```
php -dxdebug.mode=coverage /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /var/www/html/phpunit.xml.dist --coverage-html /var/www/html/cover
```

The result is always like on the first picture for modules or the second picture for all tests.

for modules:
[image]

for all tests:
[image]

- I tried to move tests into `App` namespace, it's not working.
- I searched if it wasn't from Symfony, but I don't see why.
- I tried to move `bootstrap.php` into `./` but not working.
- I tried to move code into `App` namespace, **it's working** but I don't want this.

The main thing I don't understand is that tests are all working well and only coverage is stuck into the `src` directory...

Answer (score 0):

Seems PHPUnit depends on the folder where is it launch.

The following command is working well but that means I need to execute a command for each module... At least I have the coverage now.

```
cd modules/XXX && php -dxdebug.mode=coverage /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /var/www/html/phpunit.xml.dist --coverage-html /var/www/html/cover
```

<sub>Note: Solution provided by OP on question.</sub>