# Laravel: include folders in PHPUnit's Coverage-report (if outside of app/ folder)?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage

I have small problem here after refactoring my Laravel application to be modular when doing PHPUnit Coverage report.

**This is my directory structure after refactoring:**

```
laravel-project/
├── app/
│   ├── Exception
│   ├── Providers
│   └── ...
├── modules/
│   ├── ModuleA/
│   │   ├── Services
│   │   ├── Http/
│   │   │   ├── Controllers
│   │   │   └── Requests
│   │   └── Models
│   └── ModuleB/
│       └── ...
├── tests
└── ...
```

**This is my phpunit xml configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd" 
    bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" 
    colors="true">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./modules</directory>
        </include>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">./modules/*/database</directory>
        </exclude>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="APP_URL" value="https://nginx"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="/var/www/html/database/database.sqlite"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="redis"/>
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="redis"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

The problem occurs when i try to do phpunit coverage report `phpunit test --coverage` command where there is no any modules folder being covered on the output:

[image: Coverage report screenhsot]

When I try to remove the `processUncoveredFiles="true"` options on the coverage filter, it shows the modules coverage **BUT**, every tests I've been created (even though it's calling methods inside modules folder), still it won't increase the coverage percentage of the modules coverage report.

Has anyone encounter this issue before when trying to include coverage/tests other than app/ folder of Laravel?

How To Include Folder outside app/ to Phpunit Coverage Report, e.g. Modules or Database folder which has same directory level as the app/ folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on PHPUnit version (sometime even Laravel versions).

Here is what works for me:

```xml
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">./modules</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">./modules/**/database</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Try above instead of `<coverage ...>` tag, I mean, remove your:

```xml
<coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
    <include>
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">./modules</directory>
    </include>
    <exclude>
        <directory suffix=".php">./modules/*/database</directory>
    </exclude>
</coverage>
```

## Example Command-line

To ensure the command is executed from right folder, without `cd` need, create `test-coverage` composer-script, like:

```json
{

    // ...

    "scripts": {
        "test-coverage": [
            "Composer\\Config::disableProcessTimeout",
            "@php -d xdebug.mode=coverage vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --coverage-html ./.build/coverage --verbose"
        ]
    }
}
```

And execute it whenever required, like:

```
composer run test-coverage
```

Finally, see result in `./.build/coverage/index.html` file.

> **Note** that I prefer HTML report, and for that, I added my `.build` folder to `.gitignore`, but feel free to change above command.
>
> Also, for Composer older than `1.9`, remove `"Composer\\Config::disableProcessTimeout",` line, and instead try something like:
>
> ```
> {
>    "config": {
>        "process-timeout": 0
>    },
> }
> ```

Comment: From this provided answer [PHPUnit x Symfony : coverage 0% outside of src directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75141741/16497066) seems like the phpunit can only run code within the directory where is the test run. Still, i can't make this working what am I intended

Comment: @AzvyaErstevanI **Laravel's `phpunit.xml` file is in the root folder of project** (which's parent of `app` folder), hence your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75141741/16497066) is unrelated to your issue, unless you manually `cd` into wrong directory each time you execute PHPUnit ???

Comment: My bad, i just found out that because i installed pcov and xdebug at the same time using docker php extensions, both are enabled, and as we know that Pcov didn't work well with xdebug. The only thing i should do was just either use pcov or xdebug for coverage report, but thanks for the workaround